# JavaScript onkeydown, return true,false

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onkeydown

I am studying Javascript and I am at this simple code:[Link](http://pastebin.com/VxJVEdk6),
I understand this code but the only thing that I don't understand is the return false.

I tried return true, and even I deleted the return line, and looked at FireFox, Chrome, and IE, and three of them didn't look like something happened so if some one can please tell me what difference does it make if I put true, false or delete the return.

Comment: Can you create sample on http://jsfiddle.net that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `onkeydown` or any other events don't use the returned value from the handler function. Whether you specify a return value or not, it doesn't matter. Event use other mean for its return value. Check here for `onkeydown` event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536938(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From code, I think there are mistake something.
It would be...

```
function keyHit(evt) {

    ...

    if (thisKey == ltArrow) {
        chgSlide(-1);
    }
    else {
        if (thisKey == rtArrow) {
            chgSlide(1);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function chgSlide(direction) {
        ...
}
```

And "return false" do nothing.

Comment: No that is not is. Here is a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ereQF/) that demonstrates it is not a problem.

Comment: Wow, I agree, this case is useful. I have tried " return xxx() " too, there is show same result.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers, so return does not make any difference?

Comment: Yes, return does not do anything, and there are many way to get result like your case, but I cannot find any reason which it use like that. so sorry about incorrect answer again.